# read mp3 decimal values

Tags: actionscript-3, mp3, decibel

I would like to read the be able to store the decibel values across intervals of a local mp3 into a text file. i think i can handle writing to a text file once i have the values(although any help would be great)
Best

i want to do this using AS3

and many thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, you must load the MP3, for example, by using [`Sound.load()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#load%28%29), or by including it in your library in the Flash IDE and exporting it for ActionScript. Then you can use [`Sound.extract()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#extract%28%29) to grab the waveform data from an MP3. This will give you the sample data back for the interval packed in a [`ByteArray`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html), which you can read out.

The samples are in the range of [-1.0, 1.0], so one simple way to calculate an intensity level for an interval is to find the maximum absolute value among the samples. Here's some example code:

```
var sound:Sound = new Sound();
sound.load(new URLRequest("sound.mp3"));
sound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded);

function onSoundLoaded(event:Event):void {
    var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    sound.extract(byteArray, 4096);
    byteArray.position  = 0;
    var max:Number = 0;
    while(byteArray.position != byteArray.length)
    {
        var sample:Number = Math.abs(byteArray.readFloat());
        if(sample > max) max = sample;
    }
    trace(max);
}
```

That will output the level for the first 4096 samples. You'll have to repeat this to get more values.